# Django Logging user id

Tags: django, logging

hi I'm wondering if there's any way to log user id in [django logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/)

and I want to store logs only for one view requests (store in database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can log anything you want. I always prefer file based logging. Here is a snippet of file based logging,

```
 import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(name)s: %(message)s')
    
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('directory_name/filename.log') # try to save log files in one directory 
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

and then you can log anything in by using `logger.info(f" user is is {request.user.id}")`

have a quick look on python logging that django used [python logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)